# PHP DateTime accept multiple formats?

Tags: php, datetime

I'm trying to construct a DateTime object with multiple accepted formats.

According to the `DateTime::createFromFormat` docs, the first parameter (format) must be a string. I was wondering if there was a way to createFromFormats.

In my case, I want the year for my format to be optional:

```
DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $date);
DateTime::createFromFormat('m-d', $date);
```

so that a user can input just `'m-d'` and the year would be assumed 2013. If I wanted multiple accepted formats, would I have to call createFromFormat each time?

Shortest thing for my scenario is:

```
DateTime::createFromFormat('m-d', $date) ?: DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $date);
```

Comment: Have you checked http://us3.php.net/datetime ? Is there a method that does exactly what you want?

Comment: @zerkms I've check many times and there does not appear to be anything similar to `createFromFormats`. I've also searched all over stackoverflow and the web and there is nothing to be found, not even a question.

Comment: ooo compound formats? I'm not sure.

Comment: so, if it's not there - couldn't you answer your question by yourself? :-)

Comment: @zerkms I could but then I would spend the rest of my life wondering if there were a trick to doing this.

Comment: What prevents you from creating a whitelist of accepted formats, check format chosen by user and then pass it to `DateTime::createFromFormat` ?

Comment: @galymzhan "If I wanted multiple accepted formats, would I have to call createFromFormat each time?" It just seemed redundant to have to a new call each time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create your own class that extends DateTime and add your own method:

```
class EasyDateTime extends DateTime {

    public static function createFromFormat($string){   
        if (count(explode("-", $string)) === 2) {
            $string = date('Y')."-".$string;
        }
        return parent::createFromFormat('Y-m-d',$string);
    }
}

var_dump( EasyDateTime::createFromFormat('01-01') );
// object(DateTime)#1 (3) { ["date"]=> string(19) "2013-01-01 05:11:03" ["timezone_type"]=> int(3) ["timezone"]=> string(11) "Europe/Oslo" }
```

Comment: I don't know what race condition means, but I was about to comment: what if the format is not valid in the first place?

Comment: @zerkms please explain why

Comment: @John Smith then it will return false.

Comment: I see, I guess this is the closest I'll get to a right answer. Instead of extending, I'm just going to take that nice `count(explode...` seeing as I'm probably not going to use this very often.